# Replacing NA values in race column? How should this issue be best approached?

Tags: missing-data, data-preprocessing, subjectivity

I am working with some data for my university to predict an individual's likelihood to accept an admission letter from the school. One predictor column is race. There are ~12,000 rows, and only ~450 are missing from the race column.

I'm wondering how I should best approach the cleaning of this column. Normally, I would do something like replace with the most common factor, but since this pertains to race I figure the issue is a bit more complicated. Some of these students are from foreign countries, so I will probably just replace those with the logical choice. Most, however, are from the US, which complicates the issue.

Does anyone have experience with modifying race values? I want to be careful with any choice I make. I appreciate any help!